# Using hash mod to sample a dataframe

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a field transactionId and I want to sample on this 
field. I'm wanting to sample on the hash of the field because the sampled data will be join to the sample of another sampled dataframe and I want tohave the same ids in both samples. Problem is I'm getting stuck on how to hash and mod within a filter, having tried various versions of this

```
scala> val dfSampled = df.filter($"transactionId".hashCode() % 10 == 0)
    <console>:27: error: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
    (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
    (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    cannot be applied to (Boolean)
            val dfSampled = df.filter($"transactionId".hashCode() % 10 == 0)
                              ^
```

`

Can anyone give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

This incorrect for two different reasons:

- you take hash of a column object not values in the `DataFrame`,
- you use incorrect equality operator.

Correct solution would be something like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.hash

val df = sc.range(1L, 100L).toDF("transactionId").show

// +-------------+
// |transactionId|
// +-------------+
// |            4|
// |           16|
// |           18|
// |           26|
// |           27|
// +-------------+

df.filter(hash($"transactionId") % 10 === 0)
```

Please note that it is using `Murmur3Hash` not hash codes.